# Finding Eigenvectors using Gauss-Jordan Elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, markov-chains

I was trying to find a diagonalisation of this matrix 3x3: 
{1, 1, -4},
{2, 0, -4},
{-1, 1, -2}

I found that the eigenvalues are -1, -2 and 2. I was told by a friend that you can find eigenvectors using the gauss-jordan elimination. Is this true? If so, what is the matrix setup of that would represent the Eigenvector for the eigenvalue -1?

I thought it was:
{1-x, 1, -4},{a} = 0 
{2, 0-x, -4}, {b} = 0 
{-1, 1, -2-x} {c} = 0

so when x = -1, 
{2, 1, -4}, {a} = 0 
{2, 1, -4}, {b} = 0 
{-1, 1, -1} {c} = 0

This setup seems incorrect, however. Especially since the eigenvector I found with my other method was:
{1},
{2},
{1}

Thank you to everyone that took their time to read this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because we have three unique eigenvalues, this method will work.

For $\lambda = -1$, setup $[A - \lambda I]v = [A + I]v = 0$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 1 & -4 \\
 2 & 1 & -4 \\
 -1 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}v = \begin{pmatrix}
 0 \\
0 \\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Doing Gauss-Jordan Elimination (RREF)

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & -2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}v = \begin{pmatrix}
 0 \\
0 \\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

From this we get

$$v = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\
2 \\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Repeat this for the two other eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks! but how do you determine from the RREF that v = {1,2,1} ?

Comment: Well, the second row is $b = 2c$ and the first row is $a = c$. Choose $c = 1$ since it is a free variable and that gives the answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry I noticed I'm stupid and this whole question was pointless but I appreciate your answer and wish you a lovely rest of your day.

Comment: Don't be hard on yourself - learning is a process and we all have our days, trust me!